# SSL validation with curl

Tags: ssl, curl

I'm trying to validate the SSL using curl command.

So far I have no luck as I'm getting the following:

```
-bash-4.2$ openssl verify -verbose -x509_strict -CAfile ca.cer server.cer
server.cer: OK

-bash-4.2$ curl --version
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.28.4 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets



  -bash-4.2$ curl -v --cacert ca.cer https://localhost:8443
* About to connect() to localhost port 8443 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: ca.cer
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=xxx,O=xxx,L=xxx,C=xx
*       start date: Dec 11 14:17:05 2017 GMT
*       expire date: Dec 11 14:17:05 2018 GMT
*       common name: xxx
*       issuer: CN=xxx,O=xxx,L=xxx,C=xx
* NSS error -8182 (SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE)
* Peer's certificate has an invalid signature.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Peer's certificate has an invalid signature.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

So the question is that if openssl validation is fine, why does curl give an error?

Comment: Could you try with `-v` and add output to your question?

Comment: That seems like a message from a curl that uses NSS and not openssl? If so, its not terribly surprising that they might work a little differently...

Comment: @randomir done - pasted the -v output

Comment: @griboedov, smells like a difference in NSS/OpenSSL implementations. But it's hard to tell anything more from that error message.

Comment: I assume you redacted the name(s) and they aren't actually `xxx`. Are the subject and issuer actually the same, i.e. is the server name identical to the CA name? If so, that causes PKI to fail completely; different entities must have distinct names. If you have or can get OpenSSL 1.1.0 (possibly on another machine and copy the certs to it), add `-check_ss_sig` to the `verify` command.